# How to add only business days

Tags: apex, date

I have a problem with adding days when creating Task.
I have a simple apex code

```
newTask.ActivityDate = Date.today().addDays(5);
```

But what i need to do is to count only business days.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

you have to have configured [business hours](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_supporthours.htm&type=5) you can use. It is necessary to have default one. That configurations defines which days are working.

Use [BusinessHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) in order to add working days to some date.

```
public Date addBusinessDaysToToday(Id businessHoursId, Integer businessDays){
    Long range = ((Long)businessDays) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return System.BusinessHours.add(businessHoursId, Date.today(), range).date();
}
```

first parameter is `Id` of `BusinessHours` that defines what days are working, and what not.

---

in this line `Long range = ((Long)businessDays) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;`  value of milliseconds is calculated, as method `add` accepts number of milliseconds to add.

```
businessDays * hours(24) * minutes(60) * seconds(60) * milliseconds(1000)
```

Comment: Ok i set up business days from monday to friday. Put the code into my class but i dont know how to call it. I used `newTask.ActivityDate = addBusinessDaysToToday(5);` but its not working

Comment: @David I showed you how to create  method if you are going to use it frequently. in your case: `newTask.ActivityDate = System.BusinessHours.add(businessHoursId, Date.today(), ((Long)5) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).date();` Don't forget to query `businessHoursId`